# Config to read the filename python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I am making a writing a function where it asks for the file name which then reads the csv with the given filename.

How do I have a config to read filename instead of prompting the user to enter the csv filename every time?

Comment: There are many ways.  You can store the name in a file as a simple string.  If there will be other config items, you can use a JSON string in a file.  You can use XML.  You can use an environment variable.  If you'll have a LOT of configuration, Python has a `configparser` module that is very flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a JSON config file (similar to what Typescript does), such as `config.json`, and then read that file in your python program.

Example `config.json`:

```json
{
    "filename": "filename.csv"
}
```

Python program:

```py
import json

try:
    with open("config.json") as config:
        filename = json.load(config)["filename"]
except FileNotFoundError:
    filename = input("config.json not found, please enter the filename: ")
```

Comment: It's generally good practice to be explicit in the `except` blocks so that a possible bug in the `try` block is not difficult to track down. For example, `except FileNotFoundError:`

Answer (score 1):

You can try [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html):

First, create a .ini file to store the filename that you python script should read:

```
# myconfig.ini
[DEFAULT]
filename=data.csv
```

Then, make your python script read it:

```
# script.py
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('myconfig.ini')
filename = config['DEFAULT']['filename']

with open(filename) as f:
    # do stuff with f
```

Comment: Nice answer, but it is simple to use a JSON file. Another option though